# Does nofollowing links prevent them from showing up in analytics?

Tags: seo

If someone clicks on a link that has been blocked from the search engines, will the external website's analytics still show which domain (or page) the user was referred from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. nofollow affects search engines only.